# Some Azure Functions in a Function App do not running

Tags: azure-functions

There are several answers here to this common question.

> What's reason why a single function (or some) in a function app are
>   not executing at all?

If you have an error or log output, it might be easy to figure out. But if there is nothing, and non of the other ideas helps, it's quite hard to figure it out.

Behavior:

1. Create a function app
2. Add several functions
3. Some work, some not. No error, no log, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this (strange) behavior could be an incomplete *host.json* file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functions": ["eibpc-telemetry-function", "eibpc-aggregation-function"],
  "functionTimeout": "00:05:00"  ,
  "extensions": {
    "cosmosDB": {
      "connectionMode": "Direct",
      "protocol": "Https"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
```

}

See the field **"functions"**: It's a list of the actually running functions. If you miss a function here, then:

- The *not listed* function is nonetheless deployed
- The *not listed* function is being visible in the portal and seems active
- The *not listed* function has an active "Run" button and you can click on it

But

**The *not listed* function does nothing.**

I think it's a weird mixture of an improper designed publishing process with flaws in the Azure portal UI.

### Solution 1

If you want to use all functions in the app than just remove the entry **"functions": []**. Default is "all".

### Solution 2

Add all function you want to use and ignore the fact that some functions are not active and the UI does not show this.